# Linux X11 Keyboard behaviour (xkb) on Windows

Tags: windows, xorg, keyboard-layout, dead-keys

I recently switched from Kubuntu to Windows and there is nothing I miss more than the Keyboard Layout on Linux. ^ + 1 would give me ¹ (even works with -: X⁻¹), AltGr + O would give me Ø, and so on.

Is there a way to get this behaviour on windows too? So far I tried [WinCompose](https://github.com/samhocevar/wincompose), however that requires me to always hit AltGr to start a sequence (which gets really annoying). I also tried to convert my `de.xbk` to .klc with [klfc](https://github.com/39aldo39/klfc) but that way half of my keyboard stopped working. Now I'm at my wits end. Is there a way to get the Linux (X11) keyboard behaviour? Or maybe is there some .klc file out there that includes this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

You may use the free [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

The following example script will map
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F121</kbd>
to `¹` and <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>
to `Ø`:

```
^1::¹
<^>!o::Ø
```

You may add as many other shortcuts as you like, but will need to
study the documentation links below.

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and
double-click it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on
the green H icon in the traybar and choosing Exit. To have it run on login,
place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)
- [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't the behaviour I want. With this I again have to use a modifier key for the dead keys like ^1 (Which I could do with WinCompose as well). Also "translating" the entire layout to AHK would be pretty tedious :/

Comment: Follow up: I would consider this solution if it was possible to replicate the dead-key behaviour. e.g.: first pressing and releasing ^ and then 1 to get ¹. Is that kind of sequencing possible in AHK? Without modifier key or having to press both keys at the same time I mean. (Also sorry for the additional question)